# R Replace missing elements in a textConnection with NA

Tags: r

If I do

```
a = read.table(textConnection('a b c d
1 2 3 4
a b c
1 2 3 4','r'),header=T)
```

I get an error

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 3 did not have 4 elements
```

How can I get R to replace the missing elements with NA rather than failing with an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `fill=TRUE`:

```
a = read.table(textConnection('a b c d
1 2 3 4
a b c
1 2 3 4','r'),header=T, fill=TRUE)

a
##   a b c  d
## 1 1 2 3  4
## 2 a b c NA
## 3 1 2 3  4
```